# Moving deployed Bot from one Azure Subscription to another

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-rm-template

i have a scenario where a partner has deployed a Bot in their test subscription and now they need to deploy the entire architecture

1. Q and A
2. LUIS
3. Cosmos DB for State Bot Service etc

to the Clients own subscription.

Whats the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: To move bots take a look here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-migrate-bot?view=azure-bot-service-3.0   and for other resources make an arm template and publish it in clien'ts sub

Answer (score 0):

For your questions,
You should have the access to the Client Azure Subscription,
so that you can migrate the resources to the Client Azure Subscription.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Eng Soon Cheah is correct, you would actually need to able to have access to the client's Azure subscription.

You can take a look at the official docs on how to move a resource group [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources).

And here's a succinct [blog](https://dailydotnettips.com/how-to-move-azure-resources-from-one-azure-subscription-to-another/) that shows how to move to a resource to a subscription that you have access to.

Double check the official doc's check list of things to move a resource, as you might be in the situation where you'd need to contact Support instead of self-service.